# Umask value isn't reflected after making changes

Tags: shell, umask

I changed `umask` from 002 to 007 in `/etc/bashrc` and in `/etc/profile`. After logging as a normal user I run `umask`, and it displays 0027. It should display 0007, but it doesn't. What should I do?

```
if [ $UID -gt 199 ] && [ "`id -gn`" = "`id -un`" ];then
   umask 007
else
   umask 022
fi

SHELL=/bin/bash
```

Comment: Could you post the code you set this with? If you used an equals sign, it won't work as you intend.

Comment: I didn't set this with any code. Actually I'm learning CentOS. Also when I reset the original value 002 then also the output of Umask is 0027.

Comment: Could you add the lines in your /etc/bashrc file that set the umask value, then?

Comment: Also, do you mean that the umask value is 002 instead of 0027?

Comment: No. By default it was 002 and I changed it to 007 then output was 0027. Again when I put default value 002 then it should give default output which is 0002 but output was 0027.

Comment: @clk I don't know whether it is correct or not but now i changed values again to 007 and closed the terminal and started again and checked umask. Now it shows value 0007. Is it valid step to do ?

Comment: So your `/etc/bashrc` file is as shown in the post and the umask value is 0007 when you log in as a regular user? That's what you need, right? Seems like it works then.

Comment: Yes but I mean is it necessary to exit the terminal to reflect the changes ? Will it not display after exiting from root to normal user ?

Comment: I think you would either have to log into a new terminal or source the bashrc file from within the existing terminal for the change to be made.

Comment: what does it mean by source the bashrc file ?

Comment: In this case, you can type `source /etc/bashrc` after changing the file. That will make the changes take effect within the current terminal.

Comment: You're welcome. Before, when you were getting the value of 0027, were you logging in as a different user from the same shell?

Comment: @clk No, I was logging in with same user. When I logged in as different user it showed 0007, but not for same user.